# Django session control - phpsessid cookie?

Tags: python, django

I have two very similar Django-powered sites that, for some reason, are handling session control differently. One site is issuing four cookies: `_ga`, `_gat`, `sessionid` and `csrf_token`. The second site issues a fifth: `PHPSESSID`.

I suspect that this `PHPSESSID` cookie is getting issued through a piece of middleware, but after two days of beating my head against the wall I've been unable to confirm this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I would like to figure how this cookie is issued and if I should be concerned that my four-cookie site isn't bothering with it.

Edit to update with additional info:

- Both sites issue four cookies when run locally with `runserver` - it's only in production that one site begins issuing the fifth cookie.
- Neither production server has PHP installed
- `grep -R "PHPSESSID *"` only turns up one semi-interesting result, where it looks like someone is trying to use my site as a proxy.

These requests are rejected by the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting, though:

```
log/nginx/access.log.1:185.4.227.194 - - [08/Jan/2015:20:53:09 -0500] "GET http://24x7-allrequestsallowed.com/?PHPSESSID=1rysxtR500143PRWJWU%40YCDXJBS HTTP/1.1" 400 37 "-" "-"
log/nginx/access.log:185.4.227.194 - - [14/Jan/2015:01:09:11 -0500] "GET http://24x7-allrequestsallowed.com/?PHPSESSID=1rysxtR500143PRWJWU%40YCDXJBS HTTP/1.1" 400 37 "-" "-"
```

Comment: Do you get this session cookie only in the production environment or also if you are testing it with Django's ``runserver``? (and serving static and media files by ``runserver``)

Comment: You know, I hadn't checked - and I am surprised by the results. Locally with `runserver` both sites issue four cookies. It's only in production that one site starts issuing the `PHPSESSID` cookie.

Comment: Perhaps a mischievous have changed [session cookie name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#session-cookie-name)

Comment: What I could think of is that in a production environment, the server that serves the ``staticfiles`` might be a server that has support for ``PHP`` enabled. Now, if there is anything in the staticfiles that opens a PHP session, this could be the reason for it. Could you think of any file/any service that might invoke a PHP script that starts a PHP session there?

Comment: Another option is that (if PHP is enabled on the server that serves the ``staticfiles``) has ``session.auto_start = 1`` in its ``php.ini`` or in a ``.htaccess``. You could check that by adding a PHP file to your ``staticfiles``, adding ``<?php echo php_info();`` and then opening that url in your browser.

Comment: I am totally mystified now. Neither production server even has PHP installed.

Comment: Have you grepped project files in order to math "PHPSESSID" pattern? ( grep -R PHPSESSID * )

Comment: Ok, if PHP is not installed then this can't be the reason. :) It happened to me once on webfaction, so it was at least a possibility. I will remove the two related comments.

Comment: @danihp - I edited some more information into the question. I don't have a new `session_cookie_name` defined in my settings, and my grep results are weird.

Comment: Nope; I do have a `MEDIA` directory with user-uploaded content, but no files from that directory are not reflected in the search.

Comment: Sorry, I misread, from what I understand now grep for those 4 files just returned permission denied (and not a match).

Comment: The error was mine, I was misreading the output and generally being dumb. Continued poking around did reveal a PHPSESSID in the nginx access logs; I've edited that in.